# Basic wordpress based sql query help needed

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm not big on SQL queries so could use a hand here..

In the wp_postmeta table I want to update all of the meta_value fields where the meta_key field is equal to either file_1, file_2 or file_3. I want to prepend the current content of meta_value with a string of text (string is currently image-1.jpg or similar).

I'm comfortable running a query through phpmyadmin. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value=CONCAT("image-1.png", meta_value)
WHERE meta_key="file_1" OR meta_key="file_2" OR meta_key="file_3";
```

Try it before. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. See [Update Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value =  CONCAT("image-1.jpg", meta_value)
WHERE meta_key IN(file_1, file_2, file_3);
```